# Как разбить теги html в массив?

Tags: javascript, html, массивы, строки

Например, есть строка

```html
<div>text parent <span>text span</span></div><div>text 1</div><div>text2</div>
```

мне нужно получить массив из 3 элементов

```js
['<div>text parent <span>text span</span></div>','<div>text 1</div>','<div>text2</div>']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var html = new DOMParser().parseFromString( '<div>text parent <span>text span</span></div><div>text 1</div><div>text2</div>', "text/html");
var divs = html.body.querySelectorAll('div');
var tags = [];
for(let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
  tags.push(divs[i].outerHTML);
}
alert(JSON.stringify(tags));
```

Comment: это сработает для элементов, а не для строки

Comment: у меня нет дом дерева. нужно именно строку разбить.

Comment: Изменил ответ ))

Comment: это именно оно. спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

Т. к. это не AST, а одномерный массив, то нет возможности обрабатывать вложенные теги.
Тогда как-то так:

```js
let str = '<div>text parent <span>text span</span></div><div>text 1</div><div>text2</div>';

function parse(str){
  let offset = 0, result = [];

  // Ищем очередной <div>
  while((offset = str.indexOf('<div>', offset)) !== -1){
    let closed;

    // Ищем ближайщий закрывающий тэг
    // Если его нет - кидаем ошибку
    if ((closed = str.indexOf('</div>', offset)) === -1)
      throw new Error('Unclosed tag!');

    closed += 6;

    // Вырезаем часть с результатом
    result.push(str.substring(offset, closed));
    // Меняем отступ для нового поиска
    offset = closed;
  }

  return result;
}
console.info(parse(str));
```

Comment: это если внешние только дивы будут

Comment: В вопросе сказан массив, для для полноценного разбора в древо нужен объект. Я, кстати, сначала рекурсивное построение AST набросал. Потом откатился до массива, куда вложенные теги не впихнёшь.

Comment: не вижу связи с моим комментарием, если у него на вход вдруг будет строка в которой контейнером будет не только див - этот код сломается

Comment: @Grundy, проверка ошибок, модернизация и плюшки допиливать - это уже сами, тут не фриланс.

Comment: спасибо за помощь. ваш ответ отличный. но тот что выше мне подходит больше.